# sudden apparition of Office Plus "activation error 0xC004F074"

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, license, volume-license

After almost three years of using a laptop with windows 10 Pro and office 2010 plus, it has recently began a series of "activation error 0xC004F074" saying that ms office is not activated and a countdown of days before activation required.

What should I be looking for and where? in order to obtain that activation code that my system has forgotten about.

The system is an Acer Travelmate of my daughter, purchased thru an special high school program in 2015.

Comment: `0xC004F074` indicates the Office license is a VLK license.  This requires access to the Key Mangement Server (KMS) every 180 days.  The fact the laptop was purchased through an education program, it suggests, the Office license is a volume license.

Comment: why didn't it appear until now, and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to confirm if you have a VLK license to Office.  As for the reason it hasn't appeared to now, it likely had access to the KMS, until recently.

Comment: Do you have the MAK for Office 2010 activation? If you have a product key for Office 2010, we can try to do the following to activate it: Open Control Panel > Programs and Features, select Office 2010 plus, click Change > Enter a product key. Use your product key to have a try. If you forget the product key, read the following article to find it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-product-keys-with-office-12a5763a-d45c-4685-8c95-a44500213759?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US